# Hide google logo from mapview

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

On some android devices in mapview google logo are shown as gray or red rectangle. Is it possible to remove it from mapview?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Even though there might be a way of removing it you would be violating the [Terms of Service for the Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html)

> 9.4 Attribution.
>
> (a) Content provided to you through the Service may contain the trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features of Google, its partners, or other third party rights holders of content indexed by Google. When Google provides this attribution, **you must display it as provided through the Service or as described in the Maps APIs Documentation and may not delete or in any manner alter** these trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features.

As you can see in the bold part you must not alter the logo.